# Do channel hold a ledger? Or it only stored in peers? Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

According to [Fabric-node-sdk documentation](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#joinChannel__anchor)

> For a peer node to become part of a channel, it must be sent the genesis block

According to [fabric-documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger.html)

> There is one ledger per channel. Each peer maintains a copy of the ledger for each channel of which they are a member.

To join channel peer requires a genesis block, the genesis block is acquired from channel.

So does this mean that channel also holds a copy of ledger?

**Edited**
For a new network First we create channel and then peers join the channel.
So how the peers will get the genesis block when they yet not part of channel and don't have copy of ledger?
Consider the first peer who is joining channel, no other peers are joined yet.

Answer (score 0):

There only exists one consistent channel ledger across the channel held all the peers and orderers in the channel. The channel doesn't exist as a tangible entity but rather as a logical boundary allowing concurrent actions.

So, When a peer requires the genesis block or any block in a channel ledger, It is provided by the other peers in the channel by discovery service or the orderer.

The channel config in the ledger holds the info about the peers in channels along with the MSP's defined for the channel.

Comment: I edited the question, please check it. What will happen for 1st peer who join the channel when no other peers joined yet?

Comment: The orderer is requested for the channel config block before the peer is joined. in cli this is done by `peer channel fetch 0 mychannel.block -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA`.

The join channel happens after the channel config is received like `peer channel join -b mychannel.block`